# jquery SVG plugin and positioning

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm working on a background that is powered by SVG.

I made a static svg so i could finetune the graphical look of my prototype. Here is the graphical result[image: printscreen of my svg background]

I'm now in the process of converting my svg code to the [jquery SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html?#group), so that i can later easily animate elements and add some interaction.

I'm deep into the plugin documentation but there is something i don't quite get: positioning of a group's child elements is not relative to the group element.

**My static svg**

```
<g class="user" id="user-server" transform="translate(900,50)">
    <g class="label">
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1 8.4399)" class="user-name">[ you ]</text>
        <line x1="1" y1="20" x2="200" y2="20" style="stroke-dasharray: 1,2; stroke: black; stroke-width: 0.2;"/>
  </g>
</g>
```

Note how the LINE element is positioned relative to its G element.

**My jquery.svg code**

```
function iniSVG(svg){
    var gServer = svg.group({class_: 'user', 'id_': 'user-server'});
    var gServerLabel = svg.group(gServer,{class_:'label'});
    var gServerText = svg.text(gServerLabel, 52, 76, '[ pixeline ]',{class_:'user-name'});
    svg.line(gServerLabel,1,20,200,20, {strokeDashArray: '1,2', stroke:'black',strokeWidth:1, class_:'label-line'});
}
```

This renders the line absolutely positioned to the whole SVG canvas (which is 100% of the screen viewport).

Shouldn't it be relative to its gServerLabel group ? Or is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: from your original SVG I can defienitely see how your line would be translated 900 x 50 ... but from your code I don't see the corresponding translate associated with gServer. Maybe I'm missing osmething.

Comment: gServer is a group element, group elements are positioned in CSS. So i've set it in the CSS, and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the editor to get rid of the transforms andake the coding task easier?
You cam copy and paste in place in Inkscape that might do it, but there are other menu options

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not sure i understand your answer. I think you suggest i draw it in inkscape and use the xml output. Not suitable here, as the positioning will be dynamic.